# Database Synchronization

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-2006

The problem is synchronize the data at the end of the day.

How can i achieve this.

how can i achieve this ??Tell me  something releted to delphi or higher version and using internet.

Comment: check out [this tool](http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/), you will find helpful notes [here](http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.com/2012/04/if-you-must-deploy-multi-master.html), this may need just slight changes in your application, heavy lifting is on DB and external utilities

Answer (score 2):

You could continue to update your local database from your application, and then use a separate service to perform database replication with the remote location.  Take a look at [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/) open source database replication.  It actually has its origin from POS implementations.  It can capture data changes from MySQL and synchronize the data to another database asynchronously.  You can control the schedule when it syncs data, which could be at the end of the day.  It includes a conflict manager to detect and resolve any change conflicts.  If you need help, there is also a commercial version called [SymmetricDS Pro](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds) with development and production support.